# The relationship between Object and it's properties

Tags: grammar

I'm not a native speaker,trying to understand few things.

Here soda is an object. soda has some properties like colour, taste, name ,price.

---

> The Taste of soda.
>   The Colour of soda.
>   The Name of soda.
>   The Price of soda.

---

Now the question is:
Why would we say-

> "The family of 3".

Here "3" is an object but It doesn't have a property family.

> "she is the girl of my dream"

"Dream" doesn't have a property called "the girl".

I'm trying to understand how come **girl** is related to **dream** and **family** is related to **3**.

Comment: "of" has many meanings. A non-random sample of dictionaries shows [**of**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of_1) (10 definitions), and [**of**](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=of) (21 definitions).

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions in English are complex, and *of* is no exception. It can be used to indicate multiple different relations. Definitions are from [Google's definition of *of*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20of&pws=1).

> The taste of soda
>
> The colour of soda
>
> The price of soda

All these indicate "an association between two entities, typically one of belonging". In these cases, there's a *taste*, a *colour* and a *price* that belong to soda.

> The family of 3 (people)

This indicates "the material or substance constituting something". In this case, a family is made of 3 people.

> She is the girl of my dreams.

This also indicates "an association between two entities, typically one of belonging." The girl metaphorically belongs in one of the speaker's dreams.